# Indefinite integration exercise

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> **Q**: Integrate: $$\int
>  \frac{dx}{x\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\left[x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)-\ln\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\right]}$$

---

**My Attempt:**

I used the substitution $x=\sec \theta$ and $dx=\sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta$. Then the integral I (say) became:

$$\begin{align} & I=\frac{\tan \theta \, d\theta}{\left(\sec\theta - \tan \theta\right)\left[\tan \theta\left(\sec\theta + \tan \theta\right)-\ln\left(\sec\theta + \tan \theta\right)\right]}
\\ & =\frac{\tan \theta \, d\theta}{\tan \theta-\left(\sec\theta - \tan \theta\right)\ln\left(\sec\theta + \tan \theta\right)}
\\ & =\frac{\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\tan ^2\frac{\theta}{2}} \, d\theta}{\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\tan ^2\frac{\theta}{2}}-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}- \frac{\theta}{2}\right)\ln\left[\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]}
\\ & =\frac{d\theta}{1-\frac{(1-\tan \frac{\theta}{2})^2}{2\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}\ln\left[\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]} \end{align}$$

The I used the substitution $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $2\, dz=d\theta$. So, I got after some re-arrangement,

$$\begin{align} & I=\frac{2\, dz}{1-\frac{2 \ln \tan z}{\tan^2z-1}}
\\ & =\frac{2\, dz}{1-\frac{ \ln \tan^2 z}{\tan^2z-1}}\end{align}$$
Then I changed as $\tan z =p$ and $dz=\frac{dp}{1+p^2}$ and I finally got

$$I=\frac{2(p^2-1)dp}{(1+p^2)(p^2-1-\ln p^2)}$$

But, then I thought of substitutions like $m=p^2$ but I could not progress any further.

Can you tell me how to progress or, if the result is some special function?

Comment: @Moo I don't know, maths is pure rigour, belief has nothing to do.

Comment: i have no hope that we get an result in the known elementary functions

Comment: is the result (if there is one) available?

Comment: @tired No. I am unaware, if any exists.

Comment: the sun $x=\cosh(y)$ yields a massive simplification of the integrand but i don't now if it is enough

Comment: $$
I=\int dy\frac{e^y\sinh(y)}{\cosh(y)(\sinh^2(y)+\cosh(y)\sinh(y)+y)}
$$

Comment: Wolfram claims there's no result in terms of standard functions. Out of curiosity, where did you get that integral from?

Comment: interestingly the integral without the $x$ in the denominatior and a minus sign in front of $x^2$ might be written as a total derivative